# Присвоение кирилического псевдонима при выборке данных (select)

Tags: oracle, php, sql, select, база-данных

Здравствуйте!

Мне необходимо при выборке присвоить псевдоним. НА латинеце получается. А как сделать на кирилице?
сейчас запрос выглядит так:

```
select test AS tester From testoma order by test
```

а нужно так:

```
select test AS Тестер From testoma order by test
```

скрипт не отрабатывает.

Подскажите как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: А что за ошибку пишет? Вообще я такого еще нигде не видел чтобы кириллический псевдоним кто-то присваивал. Навряд ли это возможно.

Comment: [error] PHP Warning: oci_execute() ORA-00911: invalid character....
[error] PHP Warning: oci_fetch() ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fech....
То есть неверные символы ввел. Я сам в первый раз об этом услышал, но самое интересное такое бывает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте двойные кавычки.

```
select test AS "Тестер" From testoma order by test;
```

Есть ограничение на длину псевдонима. 30 символов на идентификатор, для русских букв будет 15 соответственно, поэтому аккуратнее.

ЗЫ Удобство в русских псевдонимах сомнительное.

Comment: пробовал так уже. и переменную подставлять.. результат - ошибка выше описанная.

Comment: [Тут работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c862/1)